# Why did MCU not show Adam Warlock in Endgame?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame

When MCU teased Adam in the end of GOTG vol 2, I was sure that he will play an important role to defeat Thanos but haven't heard of that guy since then. I thought I would see him the Endgame but they didn't show him.

Comment: He's not baked yet.

Answer (score 5):

Because that's not the story Marvel wanted to tell.

Introducing Warlock (a new character) was unnecessary and would have blunted the main thrust of *Endgame*. It's likely we'll see him in *Guardians of the Galaxy Vol. 3.*

James Gunn tweeted that he was never going to be in *Endgame*.

> Said Gunn: **“Adam Warlock will NOT be in Avengers 4** (and I’ve never said he will be in Vol. 3).” Gunn also said that Guardians of the Galaxy Vol. 3 would take place after Avengers: Endgame, then still known as just “Avengers 4” by fans.
>
> <sup>[**Source**](https://www.inverse.com/article/53473-avengers-endgame-spoilers-adam-warlock-rumors-disproved-by-james-gunn-quote)</sup>

Comment: And introducing Captain Marvel didn't have the same effect? I can understand creatively they didn't want to include the character but wouldn't have said it would have *"blunted the main thrust of Endgame"*

Comment: Captain Marvel isn't a new character. Warlock hasn't appeared before. Having Warlock solve the issue instead of the Avengers would have blunted their sacrifices and struggles.

Comment: She had one movie and no other real cameo. She's quite relatively new to the cinematic universe. The only real difference between her and Warlock was she helmed a movie. It did appear she was only inserted because the avengers needed more power

Comment: So theres 90 minutes of backstory there to watch. *Endgame* is already 3 hours long and adding another origin story for Warlock just to explain his appearance would have been superfluous.

Comment: Also, if you add in Adam, wouldn't you have to go the entire Cosmic route of Thanos fighting the various gods and courting death?